# Whats the correct loss function to use during deep Q-learning (discrete action space)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

After playing around with normal Q-learning I have decided to switch to deep Q-learning and I have encountered this problem.

As I understand, for a task with discrete action space, where there are 4 possible actions (lets say left, right, up, down) my DQN needs to have four outputs. And then `argmax` of prediction needs to be taken, which will be my predicted action (if `argmax(prediction)==2` then I will pick third action, in my case `up`).

If I use Mean Squared Error loss for my network then the dimension of output needs to be same as dimension of expected target variables. I am calculating target variables using following code:

`target = rewards[i] + GAMMA * max(Qs_next_state[i])` which gives me a single number (while predicted output is four dimensional) as I workaround I decided to use custom loss function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred): # where y_true is target, y_pred is output of neural net
    return ((max(y_pred) - y_true)**2) / BATCH_SIZE
```

But I am not sure if it is correct, from what I have read from tutorials/papers loss functions do not have this `max()` in them. But how else am I going to end up with same dimensionality between targets and NN outputs. What is the correct approach here?